# Firefox Reality Unity WebGl Scene Change

Tags: unity-game-engine, firefox, webgl, virtual-reality

Im hosting my project on Amazon S3 server and its running a Unity WebGL webpage for me. All working perfectly untill i decided to have more than one Scene in the project. When im in VR in Firefox Reality and click a button to take me to the new scene the VR image freezes on my head set. I have to exit VR and enter it again to work and the Auido clip has a delay after this too.

Not sure where to go the answer. Thanks for your help!

John

Comment: Did you add the scenes to your build options?

Comment: Yep, it changes Scene but i need to come out of Firefox reality VR and go back into it to get the Scene to not be a locked image on the head set. Works 100% in Unity.